# Overriding a class : Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, overrides, class

I want to override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`class. 
I have created one module : Ved_Catalog 
Here are my module files: 
Code from config.xml :

```
<config>
<global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_type_configurable>
                        Ved_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
                    </product_view_type_configurable>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global> 
</config>
```

code in Configurable.php :

```
class Ved_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
{
...
}
```

But this code is not working. I am not getting what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: put `<product_view_type_configurable>Ved_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>` one one single line

Comment: Yes.. It is working now. Thank you very much @Marius for your help.